# Installing Anaconda on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, anaconda

I've added deploy commands to my Elastic Beanstalk deployment which download the Anaconda installer, and install it into `/anaconda`. Everything goes well, but I cannot seem to correctly modify the PATH of my instance to include `/anaconda/bin` as suggested by the Anaconda installation page. If I SSH into an instance and manually add it, everything works fine. But this is obviously not the correct approach, as machines will be added automatically by EB.

*So my question is: how can I use Anaconda in my script?*

A couple more details:

- I've tried adding `/anaconda/bin` to the system PATH all ways I can think of. Pre/post deploy scripts, custom environment variables, etc. It seems that no matter what I do, the modifications don't persist to when the application is run.
- I've tried to include Anaconda via adding it to sys.path: `sys.path.append('/anaconda/bin')`
  to no avail. Using the following: `sys.path.append('/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages')` allows me to import some packages but fails on `import pandas`. Strangely enough, if I SSH into the instance and run the application with their python (`/opt/python/run/venv/bin/python2.7`) it runs fine. Am I going crazy? Why does it fail on a specific import statement when run via EB?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found the answer: `import pandas` was failing because `matplotlib` was failing to initialize, because it was trying to get the current user's home directory. Since the application is run via WSGI, the HOME variable is set to `/home/wsgi` *but this directory doesn't exist*. So, creating this directory via deployment command fixed this issue.

---

My overall setup to use Anaconda on Elastic Beanstalk is as follows:
`.ebextensions/options.config` contains:

> commands:
>     00_download_conda:
>       command: 'wget http://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda-2.0.1-Linux-x86_64.sh'
>       test: test ! -d /anaconda
>     01_install_conda:
>       command: 'bash Anaconda-2.0.1-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /anaconda'
>       test: test ! -d /anaconda
>     02_create_home:
>       command: 'mkdir -p /home/wsgi'

`00_download_conda` simply downloads Anaconda. See [here](http://continuum.io/downloads) for latest Anaconda version download link. The `test` commands are EB's way of letting you only execute the command if the test fails...Just prevents double downloading when in development.
`01_install_conda` installs Anaconda with options `-b -f -p /anaconda` which allows it to be installed in the specified directory, without user input, and skips installation if it has already been installed.
`02_create_home` creates the missing directory.

And finally - to use Anaconda inside your python application: `sys.path.append('/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages')`
Cheers!

Comment: To make it working I had to replace `mkdir /home/wsgi` by `mkdir -p /home/wsgi` (in case you deploy for the second time and `/home/wsgi` already exists) and I also added `test: test ! -d /anaconda` to part `01_install_conda` as it seemed that `-f` option didn't work. But otherwise great work, thanks!

Comment: Awesome, really glad it worked for you! I edited my answer to include your changes. Thanks!