# Install python modules on Elastic Beanstalk with conda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, conda, xgboost

### Problem

I am trying to install python packages that have C dependencies on AWS Elastic Beanstalk (namely : [fbprophet](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/quick_start.html) and [xgboost](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/))

Elastic Beanstalk python installs packages from `requirements.txt` by default with `pip` or `pipenv` on Amazon Linux 2

However, fbprophet and xgboost have dependencies in C that need to be compiled before installing them with `pip`. `conda` comes with these libraries precompiled so they are a lot easier to install with `conda`.

---

### What I have tried

Here is my attempt at installing them with `conda` using a `.config` file in `.ebextensions` folder :

```
commands:
  00_download_conda:
    command: 'wget http://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh'
    test: test ! -d /anaconda
  01_install_conda:
    command: 'bash Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /anaconda'
    test: test ! -d /anaconda
  02_reload_bash: 
    command: 'source ~/.bashrc'
  03_create_home:
    command: 'mkdir -p /home/wsgi'
  04_conda_env:
    command: 'conda env create -f environment.yml'
  05_activate_env:
    command: 'conda activate demo_forecast'
```

However this does not work and throws this error :

```
[2020-04-21T18:18:22.285Z] INFO  [3699]  - [Application update app-8acc-200421_201612@4/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_0_test_empty_dash/Command 03_conda_env] : Activity execution failed, because: /bin/sh: conda: command not found
   (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)


[2020-04-21T18:18:22.285Z] INFO  [3699]  - [Application update app-8acc-200421_201612@4/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_0_test_empty_dash/Command 03_conda_env] : Activity failed.
```

---

So it seems that sourcing the `.bashrc` does not create the `conda` alias

I am aware of [this question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24921415/installing-anaconda-on-amazon-elastic-beanstalk) , however it is a little bit old and does not provide enough details for my case, because it does not go through with installing packages using `conda`.

Another way would be to try and install and compile the C dependencies before `pip` installing the requirement, but I had no success there for now.

Thank you for the help !

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm anticipating this same problem when I go to deploy in a few days. My ML model based Flask app is too big to work on Heroku so trying EBS. I'll update if anything works.

Comment: I ended up using a workaround and installing the C dependancies before installing with pip